# Why is Unity cropping my image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My button in photoshop looks like this:

[image]

But when I import in in my game it turns out like this:

[image]

Hopefully you can see the upper and right border has been chopped! It's a button from the new UI stuff in 4.6, and no matter I set the "Image type" to (Simple, Sliced, Tiled, Filled) and no matter setting I cant get it to show the whole image! It also does not look sharp as the photoshop image too... any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your texture is a size that is not a power of 2.

For example, make your image `256 * 128`.

Comment: I think you mean "power of 2" instead of "multiple of 2".